# Picturebox colour depending on a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, colors, picturebox

I want to begin with the fact I'm VERY new to coding, and I don't know a lot of stuff. I lack any real code to show for this question, I hope a question will do.

Anyway, I'm to make a simple game in windows forms. Without heading into details, my idea requires 36 colored squares. I guess empty pictureboxes will do.
The question is, how do I make the picturebox be one of four colours depending on a variable, and then change with a button click?
Like if a variable X is equal to 1, then colour of picturebox is black, if it's 2 it's green. 
Is it possible?

Comment: This is definitely possible, but I wonder if you really need a PictureBox for this. I think using a simple [Panel control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/panel-control-windows-forms) instead, and adjusting its [BackColor property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) should be sufficient if all you need is solid colors.

Comment: Use a `switch` statement to switch on the values of your variable X. For each `case`, set the picture box's color. This is the simplest, most intuitive way. There are others. Also consider just storing the Color value as the variable X. (BTW: Not that much difference between a Panel and a PictureBox, so don't agonize over choosing between them.)

Comment: A question itself won't really do.  Check out [ask] and [help/on-topic] for details on good questions for stack overflow

Comment: The problem with the question and your aproach is that you don
't consider the whole picture. All UI issues must be clear before deciding on how to do it. 'What' before 'How' !! - You can draw all rectangles in a Paint event, use a TabeleLayoutPanel, a DataGridview or arrays or PictureBoxes, Panels or even Labels. But how will the user interaction be? What happens ? Are there game pieces ?etc,etc. The question is both 'Too Broad' and 'Unclear'.. - And what is worse: So far you have shown no effort to communicate with the folks who try to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible of course. You have at least 2 possible ways to do this:

1. Solution:

   Save the color (or the number) of all PictureBoxes in an array or list. Update the values when you press the Button, and loop through all PictureBoxes.
2. Solution:

   Create a new object containing the PictureBoxes and add a method to change the color. Now create a list of all the PictureBox objects and change the values if you press the Button.

Edit:

Here is the code to create a list of Panels:

```
            List<Panel> PanelList = new List<Panel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            Panel p = new Panel();
            p.Name = ($"Panel{i}");
            p.BackColor = Color.Black;
            PanelList.Add(p);
        }
```

Ah and take a Panel; a PictureBox is "too much".

Comment: Where does this idea come from that a PictureBox is somehow "more" than a Panel? The amount of memory and runtime overhead between the two is negligible, if there is any difference at all. They are just wrappers around a native window.

Comment: yes you are right. but as you can see it´s not only my opinion to use the Panel:

"This is definitely possible, but I wonder if you really need a PictureBox for this. I think using a simple Panel control instead, and adjusting its BackColor property should be sufficient if all you need is solid colors. – Christopher Kyle Horton"

Comment: Yeah, he was wrong, too. That was what prompted my comment: you weren't the only one who had this misguided belief.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe the overhead between the two controls is negligible, but then what about the controls' apparent purposes? To me, when I see a PictureBox being used, it is primarily to display a specific bitmap using the Image property. Only displaying a solid color instead seems a bit misleading to whomever has to maintain that. I would then recommend using the PictureBox only if you plan on showing images instead (now or possibly in the future), so your intention is more explicit in your design.

Comment: The `Panel` control has a `BackgroundImage` property. What might that be for? :-) @christopher

Comment: @CodyGray The PictureBox control has that property too (in fact, it is inherited from Control). But the added Image property makes its intended purpose seem pretty clear to me.